# How do I display/compare a dynamic value of a mysql row in a if statement?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, html, database

I have a checkboxes on my site that when unchecked, update their row in in the db as unchecked, and if checked,update their row in the db as checked. I am creating an ifstatement that will commence with its command if checked, and not if unchecked. I have echoed the variable and it is holding the proper value (checked or unchecked) but not sure if I am syntactically correct on displaying the state of the row in the db.

This is what I am trying and will not work. I am new at php still and thank you very much for any help.

```
if($auth->check_prof == 'checked'){// do the stuff in here}
```

Comment: Exactly what is `$auth`?

Comment: $auth->check_prof is the variable that holds the value of the checkbox. For example, if unchecked, it would be my authorized id with the value of that particular checkbox. I am really just asking how display its value in an ifstatement in a syntactically correct manor.

Comment: The if-statement is syntactically correct. You might be interested in using === (type _and_ value must match) instead of == (allowing type juggling). But now I'm confused.... a) "I have echoed the variable and it is holding the proper value (checked or unchecked)"  b) "if unchecked, it would be my authorized id with the value of that particular checkbox"   ...which one is it: "checked/unchecked" or "?/id" ?

Comment: Lets say it's unchecked, now that being said, what I have would NOT equal checked and would NOT perform the commands in the curly brackets. I am just looking how to display a row and its current value from my db in an ifstatment. make sense?

Comment: I'm still not sure, but try the === (identical) operator. It _might_ be the type juggling that php performs when using ==.

Comment: If you print the "$auth->check_prof" variable, what exactly do you get?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="auth" value="checked" />
```

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['auth'])) {
    $auth->check_prof = 'checked'; // or $_POST['auth']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem of confusing `$auth->check_prof` and `$auth['check_prof']`.

Are you sure $auth is an object? If not, try `if ($auth['check_prof'] == 'checked')`.